# How to handle search for custom fields in form for FROM and TO fields?

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, search, extjs, information-retrieval

I have just started implementing search module in a project, where I have a form with fixed fields consisting of combo box, text box, radio button etc (around 200 fields in multiple tabs), and later client should be able to add extra fields too. Once user fills the fields which he wants to search, that search criteria also he should be able to save. For all these reasons, for each field I am associating metadata in the following format.

"EntityName.attributeName": attributeValue

Once the user fills the form fields to search, I will validate form data and and only non empty fields metadata I am sending to server in JSON format. Everything is fine till now. But I am facing an issues now.

Using the metadata of each field I will create a new criteria for each field. but if there are fields where one field metadata depends on other field metadata I am struck.

In the form I have few special category fields in following format : for example DOB,

FROM DATE (meta data: entity1.dob)
TO DATE (meta data: entity1.dob)

- both fields belongs to same entity and same column only field name in the UI is different

Like this I have around 20 fields which asks for FROM and TO to query the range (it need not be on date, for example no of bed rooms..it can be on integer, string etc)

My query formation should be in the following way depending on user search criteria. If user entered only FROM field of number of bed rooms then I have to query using EQUAL to operator in sql and if both mentioned then MORETHANEQUAL to for FROM field and LESSTHANEQUAL to for to field. So how I can handle this special case ?

like if he entered number of fields as 4 in TO field of number of bed rooms, then I have to query for houses having number of bed rooms equal to 4. but if in FROM he entered 3 and in To if he entered 7 then I have to query for houses having greater than or equal to 3 bed rooms and less than or equal to 7 bed rooms.

Since I have same metadata for these category fields also I am unable to proceed, to achieve this, what kind of metadata I need to prepare ?

How I can generalize this process to handle all the cases ?

- my technology stack: ExtJs, Eclipse Link, spring.
- and what are the best practices to follow to support custom fields adding feature in Forms in enterprise applications ?

Answer (score 0):

Off of the top of my head, I would create wizards for these particular cases. So for example, have a custom wizard that allows the user to define a "from" field, a "to" field, and then the comparison operator in one action. This wizard could also be responsible for adding custom properties to the generated fields that could be used by your validation routine. So based on the combo of from, to, and operator, you could create a flexible validation mechanism for ensuring that correct values are entered, ranges are correct, whatever.

You might consider this "wizard" approach for all custom fields, in fact. I could see you predefining all the possible custom field types that could be used and create classes that can be used for those. The classes could be responsible not only for the field creation, but also for providing any custom validation, pre-submit transformation, etc. This approach would make adding new custom field types incredibly simple since all you'd have to do is follow the same implementation as the others that already exist, extend an existing one, etc.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. can you please elaborate more, I am new to the concept of Wizards and also If possible can suggest any alternate approach